# Labeling vertices of a solid

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have to label the vertices of the following solid (cube) so that the labels do not overlap with boundaries of the solid.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \n/\x/\l/\p in{
1/{( 0  , 0)}/{$x_1y_1z_1$}/below,
2/{( 4, 0)}/{$x_1y_2z_1$}/below,
3/{( .8, 1)}/{$x_1y_2z_2$}/right,
4/{( 4.8, 1)}/{$x_1y_1z_2$}/right,
5/{( 0, 4)}/{$x_2y_2z_1$}/above,
6/{( 4, 4)}/{$x_2y_1z_1$}/above,
7/{( 0.8, 4.8)}/{$x_2y_1z_2$}/above,
8/{( 4.8, 4.8)}/{$x_2y_2z_2$}/above
}
{
        \node[inner sep=2pt,circle,draw,fill,label={\p:\l}] (\n) at \x {};
    }
\draw (1) -- (2) -- (6) -- (5) -- (1);
\draw (5) -- (6) -- (8) -- (7) -- (5);
\draw (2) -- (4) -- (8) -- (6) -- (2);
\draw[dashed] (1) -- (3) -- (4);
\draw[dashed] (3) -- (7);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having the labels "not overlapping the boundaries" is possibility subjective. Is this sufficient?

[image]

This was achieved by the following small changes to your code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \n/\x/\l/\p in{
1/{( 0  , 0)}/{$x_1y_1z_1$}/below,
2/{( 4, 0)}/{$x_1y_2z_1$}/below,
3/{( .8, 1)}/{$x_1y_2z_2$}/south east,
4/{( 4.8, 1)}/{$x_1y_1z_2$}/right,
5/{( 0, 4)}/{$x_2y_2z_1$}/left,
6/{( 4, 4)}/{$x_2y_1z_1$}/south west,
7/{( 0.8, 4.8)}/{$x_2y_1z_2$}/above,
8/{( 4.8, 4.8)}/{$x_2y_2z_2$}/above
}
{
        \node[inner sep=2pt,circle,draw,fill,label={\p:\l}] (\n) at \x {};
    }
\draw (1) -- (2) -- (6) -- (5) -- (1);
\draw (5) -- (6) -- (8) -- (7) -- (5);
\draw (2) -- (4) -- (8) -- (6) -- (2);
\draw[dashed] (1) -- (3) -- (4);
\draw[dashed] (3) -- (7);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I have only changed some of the `\p` values in the loop, using `south east` and `south west`, and `above` instead of `below`, in a few places. If this isn't what you want then please give more details about how you want the labels to be placed.

Btw, it is much easier to draw a [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) cube if you use 3D coordinates. For example, the code

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[thick](2,2,0)--(0,2,0)--(0,2,2)--(2,2,2)--(2,2,0)--(2,0,0)--(2,0,2)--(0,0,2)--(0,2,2);
  \draw[thick](2,2,2)--(2,0,2);
  \draw[gray](2,0,0)--(0,0,0)--(0,2,0);
  \draw[gray](0,0,0)--(0,0,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Comment: This is enough. Thank you very much, sir .@ 
Przemysław Scherwentke